# Binary search algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary

I am new to programming so please help me completing the task
the problem is:
After pressing y the while loop does not run again.
and secondly, how to print or get the array elements in descending order?

thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int item;
    int flaging = 0;
    int ind_low = 0;
    int ind_high = 9;
    int ind_mid = (ind_low + ind_high) / 2;
    char conti;

    //Array declaration and taking user input
    int arr[10];

    cout << "enter some values here : \n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    // for sorthing the array
    int temp;
    for (int p = 1; p <= 9; p++)
        for (int c = 0; c <= 8; c++)
            if (arr[c] > arr[c + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[c];
                arr[c] = arr[c + 1];
                arr[c + 1] = temp;
            }

    do {
        //asking for searching

        cout << "Enter the value you want to search : " << endl;
        cin >> item;

        while (ind_low <= ind_high)
        {
            if (item == arr[ind_mid])
            {
                cout << "At " << ind_mid << " index the value " << item << " is found " << endl;
                flaging++;
                break;
            }

            if (item < arr[ind_mid])
            {
                ind_high = ind_mid - 1;
                ind_mid = (ind_low + ind_high) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                ind_low = ind_mid + 1;
                ind_mid = (ind_low + ind_high) / 2;
            }
        }

        if (flaging == 0)
        {
            cout << "Value not found" << endl;
        }

        cout << "To search again press 'y', to exit press any key" << endl;
        cin >> conti;
    } while ((conti == 'y') || (conti == 'Y'));

}
```

Comment: For searching, why are you not using [std::find / std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: For sorting stuff, use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: I see lots of bugs in teh code, but after the loop if `y` is entered, it should at least ask for `"Enter the value you want to search : "` before it fails. What exactly do you mean by "the loop does not run again"?

Comment: Did you press enter after pressing Y?

Comment: To be fair `p` is not being used as an array index.

Comment: by loop not running I mean:

Comment: that the do-while loop should start running again and again, until the user manually stops the program, and should start searching for another element in the previously entered elements

Comment: See `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`, so you only need to make one comparison with letters.

Comment: Looks like you can factor out the `ind_mid` assignment from the `if` and `else` statements and place it following the `if` statement.

Comment: the problem is not pointed out still, why the (while) loop in the (do-while) loop is running after pressing the 'y' character?

Comment: is not running after pressing the 'y' character?

Comment: @BilalKhanHameed You have 2 questions here: "How do I stop after pressing `y`?" and "How to print the array in descending order?". These are distinct and should be asked separately. Doing so would get you better answers and would allow you to "boil down" the issues to their respective simplest forms. This, in turn, might enable you to figure it out by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

when I ran it on my pc after pressing y it did run again, can you provide the input that failed you? 
for the second question what do you mean?
you can do a for loop that goes like this:

```
for(int index = ARR_SIZE -1 ; index >= 0 ; --index){
cout << array[index];
}
```

edit: I understand what you mean. after each run you should reset your indexes otherwise you will always run on the same once:

before you end the loop the values should be reseted.

```
ind_low = 0;
ind_high = 9;
ind_mid = (ind_low + ind_high) / 2;
```

that gonna print the array from end to start.